# Open image url in html

Tags: html, amazon-s3, image-uploading, digital-ocean

I have two same images

1) https://ps-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/e60ead29-564e-432a-97e5-9ca594ac3a1c/jBdKW3pwW_PjBrtlK0hLhg.jpg

2)https://flowster-files.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/1573862824506-ContainerFarming.jpg

First image open in browser while other downloads, how can i open second image in browser as the first one, please explain what is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the Content-type for both requests. One that is loaded in browser is with a Content-Type: image/jpeg while the other one which is downloaded has Content-Type: application/octet-stream.